The problem arises from adding metric entries between geth and influxdb
I am trying to measure disk read and write amplification on the mainnet Ethereum network in a PoS environment using Geth1.14 version.
However, there was no geth metric to derive data that I was satisfied with.
So I added a new metric to geth version 1.14.
ldb := &Database{
        fn:       file,
        db:       db,
        log:      logger,
        quitChan: make(chan chan error),
        //New Add here
        leveldbWriteBytes: metrics.NewRegisteredMeter(namespace+"leveldb/writebytes",nil),
    }
    ldb.compTimeMeter = metrics.NewRegisteredMeter(namespace+"compact/time", nil)
    ldb.compReadMeter = metrics.NewRegisteredMeter(namespace+"compact/input", nil)
    ldb.compWriteMeter = metrics.NewRegisteredMeter(namespace+"compact/output", nil)
    ldb.diskSizeGauge = metrics.NewRegisteredGauge(namespace+"disk/size", nil)
    ldb.diskReadMeter = metrics.NewRegisteredMeter(namespace+"disk/read", nil)
    ldb.diskWriteMeter = metrics.NewRegisteredMeter(namespace+"disk/write", nil)
    ldb.writeDelayMeter = metrics.NewRegisteredMeter(namespace+"compact/writedelay/duration", nil)
    ldb.writeDelayNMeter = metrics.NewRegisteredMeter(namespace+"compact/writedelay/counter", nil)
    ldb.memCompGauge = metrics.NewRegisteredGauge(namespace+"compact/memory", nil)
    ldb.level0CompGauge = metrics.NewRegisteredGauge(namespace+"compact/level0", nil)
    ldb.nonlevel0CompGauge = metrics.NewRegisteredGauge(namespace+"compact/nonlevel0", nil)
    ldb.seekCompGauge = metrics.NewRegisteredGauge(namespace+"compact/seek", nil)
    ldb.manualMemAllocGauge = metrics.NewRegisteredGauge(namespace+"memory/manualalloc", nil)

    //New Add here
    ldb.leveldbGets = metrics.NewRegisteredCounter(namespace+"leveldb/Read/gets", nil)

Added ldb.leveldbGets and leveldbWriteBytes.
However, even if it is built by executing “make geth”, the corresponding metric is not added to InfluxDB. What's the problem?
Currently geth is version 1.4. influxdb is version 1.6. Previously, we confirmed that metrics were added in Geth version 1.10.26, but it is not working in geth version 1.14. Could it be a version issue?
The newly added metric should be visible when you show measurements in InfluxDB.
